# Solely one single entry per thread (question + answer) in search result.

Tags: support, search

Can the search engine return exclusively one entry/result for each thread (ie question + all answers)? The use of [questions] and/or [answers] wouldn't help because one but not the other might contain the search terms.

For example, the input of [[quantifiers] order quantifier difference](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=[quantifiers]+order+quantifier+difference) in the search engine spawns three results for [Is $\forall x\,\exists y\, Q(x, y)$ the same as $\exists y\,\forall x\,Q(x, y)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304217/is-forall-x-exists-y-qx-y-the-same-as-exists-y-forall-x-qx-y/304221#304221): twice for two Answers and once for the Question; howbeit, I'd like only one entry for convenience and avoidance of repeats.

Comment: See also [my similar feature request on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169489/151385) and the comment from Nick Craver on it

Comment: Thanks. So we must just wait then for it?